# JS Fetch() Get Header Meta Information via Variable or Function

Tags: javascript, json, variables, header, fetch

I have multiple functions, that call fetch():

```
function FetchData(...) {
   (async () => {
      ...
      var res = await fetch(url, {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({...})
      });
      ...
   })();
}
```

I would like get the header via a Global Variable (or better a function which returns the value), but this is not working yet.

Goal is:

```
function FetchData(...) {
   (async () => {
      ...
      var res = await fetch(url, {
         method: 'POST',
         ReturnHeader(),
         body: JSON.stringify({...})
      });
      ...
   })();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function in the value of the property.

```
function FetchData(...) {
   (async () => {
      ...
      var res = await fetch(url, {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: ReturnHeader(),
         body: JSON.stringify({...})
      });
      ...
   })();
}
```